# Программно заполнить форму Angular при помощи jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Доброго времени суток

Встала задача автоматизировать заполнение форм на сайте, где используется Angular из расширения для браузера

И столкнулся с проблемой, что при попытке отправить форму обработчик не даёт этого сделать. Ни программно, при помощи jQuery, ни в ручную, пока не пробежишься по всем inputam и не заменишь что-то в ручную.

Логично предположить, что ангуларовский валидатор ждёт какого-то события.

Попробовал изначально вешать фокус:
`$('input').focus();`

Не помогло, естественно. Очевидно, что в таком случае требуется сэмулировать события ввода текста с клавиатуры.

Попробовал примерно так:

```
var k = new Event('keyup', { bubbles: true });
$('input').val("some value").dispatchEvent(k);
```

Не помогло.

Куда копать? Уже всю голову сломал.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем понял проблему. Ангуляр в расширении для браузера находится или где? И не стоит использовать jQuery в связке с агуляром, их совмещение может не работать, или даже ломать поведение друг друга. Если используете ангуляр, то используйте его до конца.

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin, Angular находится на сайте, в расширении используется только jQuery. 

Но, проблема уже решена. Чуть позже сам дам ответ.